# append all textfields in tableview cells to array

Tags: arrays, swift, append, uitextfield

I want my swift code to take the characters in each textfield and convert then into a array when func append is called. You can see the comment in the func as well. The user when the func is called will take all of the textfields in class customtv and add them to array empty. Assume that every textfield contains a int.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    var empty = [Int]()
    var appended = UIButton()
    var tableView = UITableView()
    
    var arr = [0,1,2,3,4]
    @objc func append(){
        ///append all of the textfiels into array empty. All of the textfiels are in customtv
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         
             appended.backgroundColor = .orange
             view.addSubview(appended)
             
             
             
             let VCframe = view.frame
             let height = VCframe.height * 0.8
             let height2 = VCframe.height * 0.2
             let widthx = VCframe.width
             appended.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: height, width: widthx, height: height2)
             appended.addTarget(self, action: #selector(append), for: .touchDown)
             tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: widthx - 20, height: height)
             
             tableView.delegate = self
             tableView.dataSource = self
             view.addSubview(tableView)
             
             
             tableView.register(customtv.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

 
    
    
    
    
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { 118 }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arr.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! customtv
        cell.lbl.text = "\(arr[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }
    
    
    
    
}
class customtv: UITableViewCell {
    lazy var backView : UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 6, width: self.frame.width  , height: 110))
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        print(self.frame.width)
        return view
    }()
    
    
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        backView.clipsToBounds = true
        backView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 6, width: bounds.maxX  , height: 110)
        
        
    }
    lazy var lbl : UILabel = {
        let press = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 3, width: 120 , height: 50))
        press.backgroundColor = .yellow
        press.text = String("1")
        
        return press
    }()
    
    lazy var txtField : UITextField = {
        let press = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 3, width: 120 , height: 50))

        press.backgroundColor = .white
        press.textAlignment = .center
        return press
    }()
    
    
    
    
    
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(animated, animated: true)
        addSubview(backView)
        backView.addSubview(lbl)
        backView.addSubview(txtField)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, please. This works with Swift 5.

```
    func append() {            
        let arrayTextFields = (0..<arr.count).compactMap { (tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)) as? customtv)?.txtField }
    }
```

if you want to get Int values from text fields, you can add this.

```
       let arrayValues = arrayTextFields.compactMap { Int($0.text!) }
```